# Фильтр FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW с флагом FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW трет всю кирилицу

Tags: php, json, utf-8

Не могу декодировать джейсон, он очень большой, но вот проблема в следующем, на сервер вроде как передаются данные пайлоадом (чесно говоря не очень понимаю как он работает), джейсон прилетает так строка, когда пытаюсь его декодировать получаю в `json_last_error_msg()` `Syntax error`, чтобы саму строку декодировать сначала нудно:

```
$data = stripslashes(trim(file_get_contents('Файл, где храниться пример ответа в джейсоне в формате строки.'))); // Получить контент ( на начале строкы есть такой сомвол, я так понял пробел https://i.imgur.com/CHuiEFM.png )
$data = filter_var($data, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); // И вот тут пробелма, чтобы джейсон деколдировався нуждно отфильтровать символы ASCII више 127 в противному случае будет Syntax error
```

И только тогда джейсон декодируется, но без кириллических символов, не могу понять как решить данную проблему, возможно смена кодировки строки или ещё что-то, но не могу понять с какой на какую менять, совсем непонятно почему с корилицой проблемы...

Comment: попробуйте перекодировать под свою кодировку сначала https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: @AlexKhonko пробовал, результату не принесло(((

Comment: добавьте данных в описание, сложно вот так гадать по кофейной гуще